# If span contains exact text, add class to certain element on page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this code below.

```
    $("span.number").filter(function() {
    if (return ($(this).text() === 'PENDING')) {
        $(".property-thumb").addClass("pending");
    } 
    if (return ($(this).text() === 'PENDING INSPECTION')) {
        $(".property-thumb").addClass("pendinginspection");
    } 
});
```

Simply speaking, if "span.number" contains PENDING or PENDING INSPECTION, I want certain classes to be added to ".property-thumb". Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the `return` keyword in an `if` statement.That is invalid syntax.
Instead of `filter` use an [`each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) loop and remove the `return` statement.

In the loop get the select the current element being looped over with `$(this)`, find the parent in which it is in with [`parents()`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) (this is to create a context of which thumbnail it should select), and select the thumbnail element from the parent with [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/#find-selector).

Check with each item in `$("span.number")` if the text is either `PENDING` or `PENDING INSPECTION` with an `if...else if` statement and then add the classes accordingly to the thumbnail.

Tip: the `$` before a variable can be a way to indicate that the value is a jQuery object so you know what kind of value it is and what you can do with it.

```
$("span.number").each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var text = $this.text();
  var $property = $this.parents('.property');
  var $propertyThumb = $property.find('.property-thumb');
  if (text === 'PENDING') {
    $propertyThumb.addClass("pending");
  } else if (text === 'PENDING INSPECTION') {
    $propertyThumb.addClass("pendinginspection");
  } 
}
```

Comment: This makes perfect sense but doesn't work. See this link: [link](https://www.bothellhomes.com/search/results/my/qaxqmj/qazlaj/alert/__GRAY__?login=3vmjifmz0m8erp8wsjp6hawom&utm_source=propupdate)

Comment: Check the link again. It looks like it's making all of them PENDING INSPECTION, probably due to "Pending" being in both texts, correct? How would I fix that? Thanks again!

Comment: Well that is what your code does and not part of your explanation of what it should do. It loops over all `<span class="number">` elements and based on that text changes **all** `".property-thumb"` elements. And since it will add a class only once it will probably add both of those classes to each thumbnail element, should both `'PENDING'` and `'PENDING INSPECTION'` occur as text in the spans.

Comment: Ah true I didn't explain that it should not add both of the classes if one matches. My bad. This is why I wanted to use the filter based on my research. Is this more complicated now?

Comment: Filtering would be a good way to do that, although you would have to filter twice to get the correct thumbnails (for both `'PENDING'` and `'PENDING INSPECTION'`  and add the classes separately. In this case I've added lines where it looks up the element it is in and changes the class of the thumbnail that has the same parent (or more precise; grandparent) as the span.

Comment: Wow, that worked perfect. I don't quite understand how right off the bat, but I will study what you did. Thanks so much man!!

Comment: You are welcome! Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted so that it might help others in the future with the same query.